# Firebase function says deployed but won't show up in Firebase Console

Tags: javascript, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to add a notification feature to my app so that once a user makes a post anyone subscribed to them will be notified. Currently I'm trying to write a cloud function to accomplish this.

However, writing a small test fails to be deployed to my project.

Note:If anyone has links for how to accomplish something like this for Flutter it would be greatly appreciated.

I've looked at the few examples I could find and the trend has been something wrong in the js code but I can't see any.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendNotification = 
functions.firestore.document('Orders/{resturantId}/Orders')
.onWrite((change, context) =>{

const notificationContent = {
            notification:{
                title: "/*App name */",
                body: "You have a new Comment!",
                icon: "default",
                click_action: "/*Package */_TARGET_NOTIFICATION"
        }
    };

    return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("-LV_05ip0wf1dFEg45wx", notificationContent)
    .then(result => {
        console.log("Notification sent!");
        return;
    });
});
```

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to show the entire output of `firebase deploy` that confirms that the function was deployed.

Comment: looks like your .js file is misplaced or you're running the firebase cli on the wrong part of the path - double check those things...

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? Checking the path it shows that I have an index.js inside

Answer (score 0):

Being unfamiliar with the environment I didn't realize I selected type script when initializing the firebase function. So instead of index.js I should've been using index.ts.

Furthermore, a correct function deploy actually looks like this.

[image]